# Decaying velocity model

Tags: physics, vectors

I am reading a paper that goes:

> [image]
>
> Here *tau* accounts for timing and sensor inaccuracies (inherent of the operating system available on mobile phones) by providing a decaying velocity model, preventing unwanted drift at small accelerations [...]

My question is:

how can that be a decaying model, if the previous velocity is summed to something? If *tau* is a constant, I do not see any value in *R* that can always satisfy what they are saying.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The velocity does not necessarily decay. I think the word "damping model" might be a better name. Because it essentially adds a damping term to the acceleration such that the velocity does not change that much.

Let's say the original model is

$\vec{v}^{k+1} = \vec{v}^{k} + \Delta t R_B(\vec{a}_B^k - g_B)$,

and the "damping model" is

$\vec{v}_I^{k+1} = \vec{v}_I^{k} + \tau \Delta t R_B(\vec{a}_B^k - g_B)$,

then you have
\begin{equation}
\frac{|\vec{v}_I^{k+1} - \vec{v}_I^{k}|}{|\vec{v}^{k+1} - \vec{v}^{k}|}= \tau < 1.
\end{equation}